# Android DisplayManager createVirtualDisplay?

Tags: java, android, rom

anybody knows what this method does, anybody has some sample code? Anybody used this before?

The method is createVirtualDisplay() inside DisplayManager

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's for rendering the current context display virtually (off screen). Probably for video output and or capture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these functions:

```
Display getDisplay(int displayId)
```

Gets information about a logical display.

```
Display[]   getDisplays()
```

Gets all currently valid logical displays.